# trouble connecting to PDO but mysqli works just fine

Tags: php, pdo

what seem to be the problem because my credentials are correct and it did connect when i use `mysqli oop` but failed when i use `pdo`. i am using 000webhost as my self study ftp site. i keep on searching for answers but cannot seem to resolve it by myself.

error in pdo:

> connect error: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user
>   'a1882281_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

why is localhost in there when my host is mysql9.000webhost.com?

isn't it supposed to show 'a1882281_user'@'mysql9.000webhost.com'?

```
// mysqli oop, working
<?php

$host = "mysql9.000webhost.com";
$username = "a1882281_user";
$password = "********"; //my password is all numbers
$db = "a1882281_db";

$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db);

if(!$conn){
echo "error connecting: " . $conn->error;
}

$sql = "SELECT firstname FROM Friends";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
echo $row['firstname'];
}

$result->free();
$conn->close();

?>



// pdo, cannot connect :(
<?php

$host = "mysql9.000webhost.com";
$username = "a1882281_user";
$password = "********"; //my password is all numbers
$db = "a1882281_db";

try{
$conn = new pdo("mysql:host = $host; dbname = $db", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

}catch(PDOException $ex){
echo "connect error: " . $ex->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Comment: `$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db",$username,$password);` remove spaces in between and check once

Comment: omg how in the world when i remove spaces it worked? its been weeks i am troubleshooting this connect issues. how come space is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error had to do with the spaces that existed in the string inside:

```
$conn = new PDO("/*...string inside here...*/", $username, $password);
```

The following complete code should work fine:

```
<?php
$host = "mysql9.000webhost.com";
$username = "a1882281_user";
$password = "********"; //my password is all numbers
$db = "a1882281_db";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please don't be in a hurry to just drop in code. There is a specific reason as to why it's failing.

Comment: Oh, and that's not my downvote btw.

Comment: Just a code dump is not an answer. Downvote is totally mine btw

Comment: @Fred-ii- hahah I found it hilarious that when I saw the downvote, I went here to see what was up, and I saw you write your message in real time saying it wasn't you.

Comment: it is working now. i never thought that removing spaces will solve my problem.

Comment: @Webeng Well, some get pretty wanky and go off on a rebel downvote spree for the person who's inside the answer *lol*. I just like to make a mention of it. I'm not saying you're a psycho here, but I just had to make a note of it. Remember, we don't know each other from Adam ;-)

Comment: @RandyB. The string in question was designed to be as is so that the relevant information can be extracted easily. Oh and if my answer is the one that worked for you, please check mark it as accepted so that future viewers know what worked for you.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  yeah I figured that was the reason why. kind of why I found it funny since I understood your concern and could imagine other scenarios that went terribly wrong for others, maybe even you, when downvoting

Comment: for just 5 minutes i got an answer now. imagine i been in a trial and error this at work. thanks guys.

Comment: @Webeng It's all about learning and for future visitors to the question. Just like when you may have asked a teacher as to why/how things are done in the classroom ;-)